# pyinstaller v3.5 Failing to Execute

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have a program with the extension .py. When you run it from cmd and conduct full manual testing, it works out 100%. After compilation, the file weight was 49 Mb. Six weeks later I needed to make changes to the source code. Changes made. The code launched from cmd worked 100%, but during compilation the file weight became 33 Mb. The compiled .exe file started with the error 'failed to execute script main' and closed. I made a backup of the code a week ago. But the end result has not changed. Compilation was performed using pyinstaller 3.5. Python version 3.7.2 The command to compile:
`pyinstaller --onefile main.py`
I tried through other commands:
`pyinstaller --debug all --onefile main.py`
the error appeared with the message "failed to excute script pyiboot01_bootstrap
I tried:
`pyinstaller --onedir main.py`
and this also did not help find the problem. Could there be a problem in the code if the .py file is fully working? I enclose the imports that I use:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import win32com.client
import os
from numb_pis import num2text
from new_rules import declination_SurName as SN, declination_Name as N, declination_MidName as MN
```

Log from cmd after use `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`:

```
76 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
77 INFO: Python: 3.7.2
78 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
79 INFO: wrote C:\Users\proni\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\pay\For_Tests\Test_v3\main.spec
80 INFO: UPX is not available.
83 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\proni\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\pay\\For_Tests\\Test_v3',
 'C:\\Users\\proni\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\pay\\For_Tests\\Test_v3']
83 INFO: checking Analysis
83 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
84 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
88 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
91 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
4710 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
4714 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\proni\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
6031 INFO: Caching module hooks...
6042 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\proni\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\pay\For_Tests\Test_v3\main.py
6466 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   PyQt5.uic.port_v3
6497 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   PyQt5.uic.port_v2
6762 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
6818 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
7891 INFO: Loading module hooks...
7892 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
7894 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
8026 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
8027 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
8216 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
8217 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
9110 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py"...
9935 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
10866 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.uic.py"...
10872 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pythoncom.py"...
11256 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pywintypes.py"...
11633 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-win32com.py"...
11728 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py"...
11729 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
12118 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
12118 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
12123 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
12125 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
12135 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
27301 INFO: Looking for eggs
27301 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\proni\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
27302 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
27312 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\proni\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\pay\For_Tests\Test_v3\build\main\warn-main.txt
27400 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\proni\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\pay\For_Tests\Test_v3\build\main\xref-main.html
27423 INFO: checking PYZ
27423 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
27424 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\proni\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\pay\For_Tests\Test_v3\build\main\PYZ-00.pyz
28510 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\proni\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\pay\For_Tests\Test_v3\build\main\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
28530 INFO: checking PKG
28530 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
28531 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
28794 WARNING: One binary added with two internal names.
28794 WARNING: ('libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\users\\proni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'BINARY')
28795 WARNING: was placed previously at
28795 WARNING: ('PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\users\\proni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'BINARY')
40106 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
40115 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\proni\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\run.exe
40115 INFO: checking EXE
40115 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
40115 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
40117 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\proni\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\pay\For_Tests\Test_v3\dist\main.exe
40150 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

After using `pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import = numb_pis --hidden-import = new_rules main.py` I got:

```
78 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
79 INFO: Python: 3.7.2
79 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
81 INFO: wrote C:\Users\proni\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\pay\For_Tests\Test_v3\main.spec
83 INFO: UPX is not available.
85 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\proni\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\pay\\For_Tests\\Test_v3',
 'C:\\Users\\proni\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\pay\\For_Tests\\Test_v3']
85 INFO: checking Analysis
86 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
86 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
90 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
93 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
4722 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'numb_pis'
4913 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'new_rules'
4927 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
4984 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
5835 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
5838 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\proni\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
7129 INFO: Caching module hooks...
7140 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\proni\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\pay\For_Tests\Test_v3\main.py
7559 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   PyQt5.uic.port_v3
7591 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   PyQt5.uic.port_v2
7854 INFO: Loading module hooks...
7855 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
7857 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
7986 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
7987 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
8184 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
8185 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
9126 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py"...
10165 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
11145 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.uic.py"...
11150 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pythoncom.py"...
11528 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pywintypes.py"...
11907 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-win32com.py"...
12004 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py"...
12005 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
12393 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
12393 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
12398 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
12401 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
12410 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
27487 INFO: Looking for eggs
27488 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\proni\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
27488 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
27498 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\proni\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\pay\For_Tests\Test_v3\build\main\warn-main.txt
27588 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\proni\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\pay\For_Tests\Test_v3\build\main\xref-main.html
27611 INFO: checking PYZ
27611 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
27612 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\proni\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\pay\For_Tests\Test_v3\build\main\PYZ-00.pyz
28703 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\proni\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\pay\For_Tests\Test_v3\build\main\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
28723 INFO: checking PKG
28723 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
28724 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
28969 WARNING: One binary added with two internal names.
28970 WARNING: ('libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\users\\proni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'BINARY')
28970 WARNING: was placed previously at
28971 WARNING: ('PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\users\\proni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'BINARY')
40338 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
40346 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\proni\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\run.exe
40347 INFO: checking EXE
40347 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
40347 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
40348 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\proni\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\pay\For_Tests\Test_v3\dist\main.exe
40381 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Please tell me what could be the problem, or how can I find out.

Comment: Probably pyinstaller fails to find all imports. Look at [`--hidden-import` option](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports)

Comment: I edited post. Look please

Comment: It looks it finds `PyQt` and `win32com`, I don't know about `numb_pis` and `new_rules`. I think you can ignore warning about `PyQ.sis`. I would try with `pyinstaller --onefile --hiden-import=numb_pis --hiden-import=new_rules main.py`

Comment: `new_rules` is my own package. And I took `numb_pis` from the Internet, this package has only 1 import - `import decimal`, which I did not use.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion in previous comment? I understand these are your modules. The question is __Does pyinstaller find and include them when creating the exe?__

Comment: Yes, i tried and got `pyinstaller: error: unrecognized arguments: --hiden-import --hiden-import new_rules main.py`

Comment: And, tried your suggestion and get `pyinstaller: error: unrecognized arguments: --hiden-import=numb_pis --hiden-import=new_rules`

Comment: sorry, but it's clear typo - I have it right in my first comment. it's `--hidden-import` with double d. You should be able to see this, right? I am not able to fix it, because one can edit comments up to 5 minutes

Comment: I updated the post. All that I could notice from the changes, I found 2 added lines:
`4722 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'numb_pis'`
`4913 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'new_rules'`